# how to add params to firebase dynamic link on backend server?

Tags: java, firebase, url, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I created dynamic link using Firebase http://example.page.link/home. I want to add token as parameter in this link on server to authentication e.g. http://example.page.link/home?token=1234.
How I can create this link on server (using Spring) and get this param from link on app(Flutter)?

Answer (score 0):

Marcin the best way to add authentication to the backend is using .php to authenticate the user and use the token that is submitted to do a process.
But if you want to use it as how you put it you can but a form submits variable inside of the form they submitted assumingly that you are running .html. I can add files to show an example of both ill be happy to do that once I understand fully your question that being how does the user add the token. Happy to hear back from you. Thanks, MG.